# Date formatting (jQuery datepicker)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the date format from `mm/dd/yyyy` to `dd/mm/yyyy`.

After the date picker performs its action, I want the `dd/mm/yyyy` to display
in the text box.

```
<script>
$(function() {
        var dates = $( "#from, #to" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
    var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
    instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
    date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
        instance.settings.dateFormat ||
        $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
        selectedDate, instance.settings );
                    dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Have you had a look at the docs? http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-formats and http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#localization

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#from, #to').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy' });
```

it can help you...

Answer (score 0):

```
.datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' })
```

using dateFormat option you can change the format of date,rest whatever option you want you can provide it

Comment: instead of defaultDate: "+1w", you should write dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'